# how to connect wordpress plugin securly to a platform

Tags: wordpress, plugins, cross-platform

I 'm developing a WordPress plugin related to a platform i created earlier. The plugin will be needing some data from the database of that platform.

What is the best way to let the plugin to communicate with my external database without risking the security of my platform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write some api routes for your platform,like:
https://myPlatform/api/posts

In your wordpress plugin, request the apis of your platform.
You could use these requests packages:
https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle

You should alse do some validation while requesting your platform.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is good, but i would like to add a few things.

1) Always use secure channels for communication if the information is more likely to contain critical information (https).

2) Make good use of permission based Queries on the platform side and maybe on the plugin wordpress side check for the current logged in roles (if needed), if a particular role doesn't have to access a specific endpoint don't allow him both ways earlier checks can avoid unnecessary requests.

3) Try to make those request to the platform in a non-blocking way (ajax), to prevent unnecessary page load times.

4) Anticipate as much scenarios of how the platform will communicate its multiple messages and how your plugin should interpret them.